# Is it Possible to Convert a GRD File into an ASC File in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, convert

Is it possible to convert in QGIS a GRD file (that was created in MapInfo) into an ASC file (that can be imported into SAGA)?

Is it possible to "extract by mask" a section of a GRD file in an other format than GeoTiff in QGIS?

Comment: There are more than 1 type of GRD file.  What software was this file created in?

Comment: _It was created in MapInfo_

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add it to QGis as a new raster. If your file-format is in this [list](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) and supported by GDAL, then it will probably also be accessible in QGis.

You can "extract by mask" with the Gdal clipper tool. See this [blog post](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-working-with-rasters-in-qgis.html) for an example.